# How to force Visual Studio to update the UI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, vs-extensibility

I'm working on a Visual Studio [extension](https://github.com/TomSmartBishop/image-comments), when the `ToggleEnabled()` function is called, it triggers `OnToggleEnabled` -> `OnToggleEnabledHandler`.

At `private void OnToggleEnabledHandler()` these attempts are not working, and the UI is not being updated.

I'm trying to make it call the [LayoutChangedHandler](https://github.com/TomSmartBishop/image-comments/blob/1b1fd567a819385634d6f230789a934aa9b7363c/ImageCommentsExtension/ImageAdornmentManager.cs#L72) function.

How I could "force" Visual Studio to update its UI?

-Walkthrough-

A [shortcut](https://github.com/TomSmartBishop/image-comments/blob/1b1fd567a819385634d6f230789a934aa9b7363c/ImageCommentsPackage/ImageCommentsPackage.vsct#L35) send to VS trigger the [Execute(AsyncPackage package)](https://github.com/TomSmartBishop/image-comments/blob/1b1fd567a819385634d6f230789a934aa9b7363c/ImageCommentsPackage/ImageCommentsCommand.cs#L29) function, and it trigger the [ToggleEnabled()](https://github.com/TomSmartBishop/image-comments/blob/1b1fd567a819385634d6f230789a934aa9b7363c/ImageCommentsExtension/ImageAdornmentManager.cs#L43) function:

```
    public class ImageAdornmentManager : ITagger<ErrorTag>, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IAdornmentLayer _layer;
        private readonly IWpfTextView _view;
        private readonly VariableExpander _variableExpander;
        private string _contentTypeName;
    
        public static bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public static event Action OnToggleEnabled;
    
        static ImageAdornmentManager()
        {
            Enabled = true;
        }
    
        public static void ToggleEnabled()
        {
            ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
    
            Enabled = !Enabled;
            UIMessage.Show($"Comment: {Enabled}. Scroll editor window to update.");
            OnToggleEnabled?.Invoke();
        }
    
        public ImageAdornmentManager(IWpfTextView view)
        {
            _view = view;
            _layer = view.GetAdornmentLayer("ImageCommentLayer");
            _view.LayoutChanged += LayoutChangedHandler;
            _contentTypeName = view.TextBuffer.ContentType.TypeName;
            _view.TextBuffer.ContentTypeChanged += contentTypeChangedHandler;
    
            OnToggleEnabled += OnToggleEnabledHandler;
        }
            
        private void OnToggleEnabledHandler()
        {
            Console.Write("OnToggleEnabledHandler");
            _view.VisualElement.InvalidateMeasure();
            _view.VisualElement.InvalidateArrange();
            _view.VisualElement.InvalidateVisual();
            _view.LayoutChanged += (sender, e) => { };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be totally missing something here, but re

> "How I could "force" Visual Studio to update its UI?"

don't you just need to call update() on the layer? e.g.

```
    private void OnToggleEnabledHandler()
    {
        ...
        _layer.Update(); // Updates the layout and redraws

    }
```

See the [AdornerLayer.Update Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.adornerlayer.update?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

re

> "I'm trying to make it call the LayoutChangedHandler function."

The [ITextView.LayoutChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itextview.layoutchanged?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) is raised whenever the view does a layout. I am pretty sure calling update on the layer will cause the view to do this...although I could be wrong.

Comment: I have add `using System.Windows.Documents;` and when i try `_layer.Update()` i'm getting this error: `'IAdornmentLayer' does not contain a definition for 'Update' and no accessible extension method 'Update' accepting a first argument of type 'IAdornmentLayer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`